# NPM 7 Workspaces - Multiple node_modules?

Tags: npm, npm-install, monorepo, npm-workspaces

I'm having trouble running my app with NPM 7 Workspaces. I am expecting an `npm install` from the root folder to create a `node_modules` folder for each of my workspaces, similar to Lerna. However, when I run `npm install` at the root, I only get one `node_modules`, at the root level. **Is this expected?**

Example structure **before** `npm i`:

```
.
├── package.json ->  { "workspaces": ["packages/*"] }
└── packages
    ├── a
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── package.json
    ├── b
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── package.json
    └── c
        ├── index.js
        └── package.json
```

Example structure **after** `npm i` (note only one `package-lock.json`/`node_modules`):

```
.
├── package.json ->  { "workspaces": ["packages/*"] }
├── **node_modules**
├── **package-lock.json**
└── packages
    ├── a
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── package.json
    ├── b
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── package.json
    └── c
        ├── index.js
        └── package.json
```

Node version: `16.4.2`

NPM version: `7.18.1`

Answer (score 4):

Update: After messing around a with a million things, I finally went and deleted the project and recloned it. It worked after this. I believe it was due to the fact that I was on an old node/npm version when I originally cloned the project. Must have been some funky state lingering around there. Anyway hope this helps anyone with the same problem!

Comment: Have solved this issue with just updating npm and node version? Because in my example I see node_modules in packages but its contains only small subset of all dependencies.

Comment: @VadimB I'm  not sure I understand what you mean, sorry!